# How to add a classname to a radiolist item

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

For a project I created a new custom field type, called RadioList. This RadioList class extends the [RadioButtonList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. I use repeatlayout [UnorderedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatlayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I want to add a classname to the input tag, for example:
    `<input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" class="class-on-inputfield" />`

The classname is added to the span arround the input tag now. I don't like it.
    `<span class="class-on-inputfield"><input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" class="" /></span>`

The C# programcode.

```
List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    ListItem listItem = new ListItem()
    {
        Text = i.ToString(),
        Value = i.ToString()
    };

    listItem.Attributes.Add("class", "class-on-inputfield");
    list.Add(listItem);
}

this.RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.UnorderedList;
this.items = list;
this.DataBind();
```

Does anyone know how I could solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Answer (score 0):

```
//Default.aspx
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbListTest" runat="server">
</asp:RadioButtonList>

//Default.aspx.cs
    var liItem = new ListItem("Test", "Val1");       
    //Add class name to span element
    liItem.Attributes.Add("class", "spanClassNameHere");       
    rbListTest.Items.Add(liItem);
```

Then add the following before the closing /asp:content tag

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.spanClassNameHere').find('input[type=radio]').addClass('myNewInputTagClassNameHere');
    });
</script>
```

The output should look like this:

```
<span class="spanClassNameHere">
        <input name="ctl00$MainContent$rbListTest" class="myNewInputTagClassNameHere" id="MainContent_rbListTest_0" type="radio" value="Val1" />
        <label for="MainContent_rbListTest_0">Test</label>
    </span>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i'm restricted to use the RadioButtonList class.

Comment: What about a combination jquery/C# solution? As in the edit above